# Screen capture in Mac is all black

Tags: mac, ssh, screenshot

I'm trying get screen capture through a SSH connection. In this SSH connection, I'm using the root user.

I found that after executing this command:

```
screencapture -t jpg -S /test.jpg
```

the jpg file I got is all black. If I do this in the normal way (not through SSH), then I can get the screen capture successfully.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a command line client for the OS X screen capturing? Gosh, didn't know that.

I wonder what the man page says…

> SECURITY CONSIDERATIONS
>
> To capture screen content while logged in via ssh, you must launch
> screencapture in the same mach bootstrap hierarchy as loginwindow:
>
> ```
> PID=pid of loginwindow
> sudo launchctl bsexec $PID screencapture [options]
> ```

Comment: Snarky, I like it :-) +1